# Corner blob animation

Tags: html, css, canvas, css-animations

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864177/animating-a-wobbly-canvas-like-in-discords-login-page) a while back were someone made a corner blob animation similar to the one on the old discord login page ([jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/bde8e879b344202cf06379e44f9e80b2)). I want to move it to the right side of the page. I don't know exactly how it works.

```js
const SCALE = 0.25;
const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
const HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

class Blob {
  constructor() {
    this.wobbleIncrement = 0;
    // use this to change the size of the blob
    this.radius = 500;
    // think of this as detail level
    // number of conections in the `bezierSkin`
    this.segments = 12;
    this.step = HALF_PI / this.segments;
    this.anchors = [];
    this.radii = [];
    this.thetaOff = [];

    const bumpRadius = 100;
    const halfBumpRadius = bumpRadius / 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.segments + 2; i++) {
      this.anchors.push(0, 0);
      this.radii.push(Math.random() * bumpRadius - halfBumpRadius);
      this.thetaOff.push(Math.random() * TWO_PI);
    }

    this.theta = 0;
    this.thetaRamp = 0;
    this.thetaRampDest = 12;
    this.rampDamp = 25;
  }
  update() {
    this.thetaRamp += (this.thetaRampDest - this.thetaRamp) / this.rampDamp;
    this.theta += 0.03;

    this.anchors = [0, this.radius];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.segments + 2; i++) {
      const sine = Math.sin(this.thetaOff[i] + this.theta + this.thetaRamp);
      const rad = this.radius + this.radii[i] * sine;
      const theta = this.step * i;
      const x = rad * Math.sin(theta);
      const y = rad * Math.cos(theta);
      this.anchors.push(x, y);
    }

    c.save();
    c.translate(-10, -10);
    c.scale(SCALE, SCALE);
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0, 0);
    bezierSkin(this.anchors, false);
    c.lineTo(0, 0);
    c.fill();
    c.restore();
  }
}

const blob = new Blob();

function loop() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  blob.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

// array of xy coords, closed boolean
function bezierSkin(bez, closed = true) {
  const avg = calcAvgs(bez);
  const leng = bez.length;

  if (closed) {
    c.moveTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[0], bez[1], avg[0], avg[1]);
  } else {
    c.moveTo(bez[0], bez[1]);
    c.lineTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng - 2; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.lineTo(bez[leng - 2], bez[leng - 1]);
  }
}

// create anchor points by averaging the control points
function calcAvgs(p) {
  const avg = [];
  const leng = p.length;
  let prev;

  for (let i = 2; i < leng; i++) {
    prev = i - 2;
    avg.push((p[prev] + p[i]) / 2);
  }
  // close
  avg.push((p[0] + p[leng - 2]) / 2, (p[1] + p[leng - 1]) / 2);
  return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope these 2 changes in `update` function help you:

```
c.translate(canvas.width-10, -10);
c.rotate(Math.PI / 2)
```

Full Code:

```js
const SCALE = 0.25;
const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
const HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

class Blob {
  constructor() {
    this.wobbleIncrement = 0;
    // use this to change the size of the blob
    this.radius = 500;
    // think of this as detail level
    // number of conections in the `bezierSkin`
    this.segments = 12;
    this.step = HALF_PI / this.segments;
    this.anchors = [];
    this.radii = [];
    this.thetaOff = [];

    const bumpRadius = 100;
    const halfBumpRadius = bumpRadius / 2;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.segments + 2; i++) {
      this.anchors.push(0, 0);
      this.radii.push(Math.random() * bumpRadius - halfBumpRadius);
      this.thetaOff.push(Math.random() * TWO_PI);
    }

    this.theta = 0;
    this.thetaRamp = 0;
    this.thetaRampDest = 12;
    this.rampDamp = 25;
  }
  update() {
    this.thetaRamp += (this.thetaRampDest - this.thetaRamp) / this.rampDamp;
    this.theta += 0.03;

    this.anchors = [0, this.radius];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.segments + 2; i++) {
      const sine = Math.sin(this.thetaOff[i] + this.theta + this.thetaRamp);
      const rad = this.radius + this.radii[i] * sine;
      const theta = this.step * i;
      const x = rad * Math.sin(theta);
      const y = rad * Math.cos(theta);
      this.anchors.push(x, y);
    }

    c.save();
    c.translate(canvas.width-10, -10);
    c.rotate(Math.PI / 2)
    c.scale(SCALE, SCALE);
    c.fillStyle = "blue";
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0, 0);
    bezierSkin(this.anchors, false);
    c.lineTo(0, 0);
    c.fill();
    c.restore();
  }
}

const blob = new Blob();

function loop() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  blob.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

// array of xy coords, closed boolean
function bezierSkin(bez, closed = true) {
  const avg = calcAvgs(bez);
  const leng = bez.length;

  if (closed) {
    c.moveTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[0], bez[1], avg[0], avg[1]);
  } else {
    c.moveTo(bez[0], bez[1]);
    c.lineTo(avg[0], avg[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < leng - 2; i += 2) {
      let n = i + 1;
      c.quadraticCurveTo(bez[i], bez[n], avg[i], avg[n]);
    }
    c.lineTo(bez[leng - 2], bez[leng - 1]);
  }
}

// create anchor points by averaging the control points
function calcAvgs(p) {
  const avg = [];
  const leng = p.length;
  let prev;

  for (let i = 2; i < leng; i++) {
    prev = i - 2;
    avg.push((p[prev] + p[i]) / 2);
  }
  // close
  avg.push((p[0] + p[leng - 2]) / 2, (p[1] + p[leng - 1]) / 2);
  return avg;
}
```